# How to normalize data to a range in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I am trying to implement the following normalization logic:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range

Basically, I want to take all values from a particular measure and scale them to values in the range of [0, 1]. This requires gathering the minimum and the maximum of a measure. What I want is...

```
(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

If you create a calculated field using the above link's method, you get the "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate" error.

This is where I am stuck. Is there a function and/or trick to get this to work?

Comment: did you try attr(x) for aggregating the first instance of the variable?

Comment: ATTR(x) would only work if x is always the same value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [LOD expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) to tell Tableau that you want the min of all the x values, not just that row. Try:

```
    (x -{FIXED : MIN(x)})
    /
    ({FIXED  : MAX(x)}-{FIXED  : MIN(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I have been finding this for couple days!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
(MEDIAN(X)- TOTAL(MIN(X))) / (TOTAL(MAX(X)) - TOTAL(MIN(X))).
```

If the function only acts on one data point at a time, MEDIAN(X) will just return the value of the data point itself.

Comment: what do you do if your X is an aggregate  function already?