# Normalize a series by first value in Tableau

Tags: sql, time-series, tableau-api, division, normalize

I'd like to normalize a data series in Tableau by the first value.

If my input table is: 
date | amount 
1/1   $100 
1/2   $150 
1/3   $250

I'd like to create (and plot) the normalized values: 
date | amount_norm 
1/1   1 
1/2   1.5 
1/3   2.5

In SQL this would be

```
SELECT date, amount / ( SELECT amount 
                        FROM table 
                        WHERE date = ( SELECT MIN(date) FROM table ) ) AS amount_norm
FROM table
```

Ideally, `amount_norm` should update as the user changes the selected time interval in the Tableau dashboard filter.

Seems pretty simple, but I'm totally unfamiliar with Tableau syntax. I've tried playing with `FIRST() = 0` but don't really know what I'm doing.

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045931/how-to-normalize-data-to-a-range-in-tableau), but this didn't get me quite where I wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it the first value or minimum value ?

Comment: First value, a.k.a., value for the minimum date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the SQL code logic:

```
    SUM([Amount])
    /
   SUM({FIXED : SUM(IF [Date] = {FIXED : MIN([Date])} THEN ([Amount]) END)})
```

If you want it to adhere to filters in your workbook/dashboard you would add the dimension you're filtering on before the colon like below:

```
    SUM([Amount])
    /
   SUM({FIXED [filter dimension] : SUM(IF [Date] = {FIXED : MIN([Date])} THEN ([Amount]) END)})
```

To add more criteria for the fixed LOD expression you can add a comma and then another dimension.

Comment: Thanks -- this looks very close. I tried your simpler approach first: `SUM([amount]) / SUM(IF [date] = {FIXED : MIN([date])} THEN [amount] END)`. I see the first value is 1, and the rest are nulls. Seems like this `IF` condition is only calculating the normalized amount for the first date. Do we need an `ELSE` somewhere to compute the quotient for the other dates? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I added a little more logic to it. I had to fix one more level of detail and then aggregate it. I did the first one without looking, but this one I tested. Let me know if it does not work!

Comment: Thank you! This solves the nulls issue. However, I have multiple series and it looks like the denominator is the sum of all amounts on the first day. Imagine my input table has several columns, `amount_1, amount_2, ... , amount_n`. I was hoping that each amount column would be *normalized to its own starting value*. 

More generally, I think I need to figure out how to tinker on my own and understand Tableau expressions. I need the equivalent of a Python interpreter or running a line of SQL. For some reason, I'm having trouble simply determining the output of `MIN([date])`, for instance.

Comment: Yeah Tableau LOD expressions can be a pain. You'd have to have a calculated field for each column (changing the amount field in each one to match). If you wanted the minimum amount of the first day you could change the SUMs in the denominator to MINs. But that may not be what you're after. If you had an ID that represented the first amount of the first day that could be implemented too.

Answer (score 1):

This would be simpler with a table calc instead of an LOD calc